# How to fetch a products price from spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I need to fetch last products price through console in Spree

```
Spree::Product.last.price

 => #<BigDecimal:850ff20,'0.3394E4',9(18)>
```

In the returned value given above, .3994 is shown, 3994 is the real price.
How to return the exact price from the product or how can I parse the above price of this product from "BigDecimal:850ff20,'0.3394E4',9(18)"  to "3394"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"0.3394E4" means "3394". If all you want from it is to read it in the console, just call `.to_f` on it, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm putting this out there for me and others if you also need to display in a money format, ie: `$25.00`, then:

```
# Views
<%= Spree::Product.last.display_amount %> => $25.00

# Console
Spree::Product.last.display_amount.to_s => "$25.00"
```