# update a spree product's price from rails console

Tags: spree

somewhat related to [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42120941/how-to-fetch-a-products-price-from-spree)

How update a spree product's price from rails console?

what I tried:

```
irb(main):011:0> pp Spree::Product.last.display_amount.to_s
=> "$13.99"
irb(main):012:0>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Spree::Product.last.update(price: '1')
```